# JQuery instance update

Tags: php, html, jquery

I want to update  data with jquery, but I have two problem.
First, Jquery update data after refresh page, but I want it to be live.
Second problem, if I open the page the first time, the number of baskets shows an error.
[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy2eu.png)

```
Script code:
  $(document).ready(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'add_cart.php',
                data:{
                    total_cart_items:"total_items"
                },
                success:function(response) {
                    $("#total_items").text(response);


                }
            });

        });
```

PHP Count code

```
if(isset($_POST['total_cart_items']))
{

    echo count($_SESSION['name']);
    exit();
}
```

Show in page

```
<span id="total_items" class="total_items position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill bg-danger">
```

Comment: This is not correct `$("#total_items").text=response;` it would be `$("#total_items").text(response);`

Comment: so it was just that I was experimenting and forgot to put here the initial code, ```$ ("# total_items"). text (response);``` it is only updated with refresh

Comment: Maybe $_SESSION['name'] name key in session not found so you cannot count(null) add this count((int)$_SESSION['name']);